# Errot while Integrating Sonarqube with LDAP

Tags: ldap, continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops

```html
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://ldap-company.com
ldap.bindDn=CN=xxxxx,OU=Restricted,OU=xxxx,DC=company,DC=com
ldap.bindPassword=none

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail


# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=OU=Groups,OU=companyname,DC=comapany,DC=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
```

These are my configurations----sonarqube version-6.2
Database-Embedded

Do you guys have any idea how to integrate LDAP with Sonarqube. I tried different ways but couldn't get succeeded. this I my configuration for sonar.properties

I got an error `2017.03.15 15:57:25 ERROR web[AVrTij8L9uoXNT8qAAAK][o.s.s.a.RealmAuthenticator] Error during authentication
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to retrieve details for user xxx in <default>` and also `Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., dat`

`2017.03.15 15:55:05 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.03.15 15:55:49 ERROR web[AVrTij8L9uoXNT8qAAAJ][o.s.s.a.RealmAuthenticator] Error during authentication
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to retrieve details for user xxxxx in <default>
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapUsersProvider.getUserDetails(LdapUsersProvider.java:84)
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapUsersProvider.doGetUserDetails(LdapUsersProvider.java:58)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(RealmAuthenticator.java:89)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.authenticate(RealmAuthenticator.java:83)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthenticator.authenticate(CredentialsAuthenticator.java:56)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthenticator.authenticate(CredentialsAuthenticator.java:45)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.authenticate(LoginAction.java:91)`

This is my web.log

```html
2017.03.16 13:10:09 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2017.03.16 13:10:09 INFO  web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
2017.03.16 13:10:09 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=DC=company,DC=com, request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0})), realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribut
e=mail}
2017.03.16 13:10:09 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Group mapping: LdapGroupMapping{baseDn=OU=Groups,OU=comapny,Dc=company,DC=com, idAttribute=cn, requiredUserAttributes=[uid], request=(&(objectC
lass=posixGroup)(memberUid={0}))}
2017.03.16 13:10:09 INFO  web[][o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection: FAIL
2017.03.16 13:10:09 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database stopped
2017.03.16 13:10:09 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to open LDAP connection
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.testConnection(LdapContextFactory.java:206)
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapRealm.init(LdapRealm.java:63)
        at org.sonar.server.user.SecurityRealmFactory.start(SecurityRealmFactory.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)​
```

Comment: Did you intend to include your LDAP-related values from your `sonar.properties` file? Also, have you used an LDAP client to validate your settings independently?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I didn't used LDAP client to validate. May I know how to validate. and I added my LDAP configuration in my question

Comment: `General Configuration
ldap.realm=ldap-companyname.com
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
sonar.security.savePassword=true
ldap.bindDn='CN=xxxx,OU=xxx,OU=Service Accounts,DC=company,DC=com'
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
ldap.url=ldap://ldap-companyname.com:portnumber`

Comment: please [edit] your question to include these things. It will be easier for people who want to try to help you if they don't have to find the relevant details in the comment thread.

Comment: What are the LDAP properties you are using ?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam it showing some syntax error where I cant post in same question

Comment: I added my Ldap conf above @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam

Answer (score 1):

Your bind is failing. You need to test with an external LDAP tool like Apache Directory Studio tool, or Softerra's LDAP Browser.

It could be a firewall issue from your server to the LDAP server. It could be the password is incorrect. It does look like your Sonar server is able to talk to the LDAP server (Which looks like Active Directory) since you get an AD style error message about needing to bind before searching.

If you can get the error on the bind failing it will return an error code 49 with a subcode that is of interest.  525, 52e, 777 or the like that refer to different reasons Active Directory will not let you connect.

Note: Your password is 'none' which is hard to tell if that is you trying to hide the password, or an actual literal password.

Comment: thanks for your response. I didn't assigned any password for this

Comment: LDAP says a login with a username and no password is an anonymous bind and you will have no rights.  Set a password in your target LDAP and specify the password in your code and try again.

Comment: changed values & am able to connect Ldap but user cant acces.blw is conf  _`# LDAP
# General 
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://ldap-companyname.com
ldap.bindDn=CN=userID,OU=Corp,OU=companyname,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com
ldap.bindPassword=Paswd
 
# User
ldap.user.baseDn=DC=Domain,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
 
# Group 
ldap.group.baseDn=CN=Group,DC=company root,DC=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName`_

Comment: is there anything that I need to modify in group request or group attributes @geoffc

Comment: AD sometimes has an issue with starting a search at the root of the domain.  Are your users in a subcontainer off the dc=domain,dc=com root?  Perhaps in cn=Users or ou=People?  Consider trying that. Also make sure that the valye they enter as username is really a samaccountname value.

Comment: I will check and will try it. Thanks for the fast response @geoffc