# SonarQube 5.6 with LDAP 2.1.0.507 plugin

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube

I am running SonarQube 5.6 in a docker machine with the following settings.

> ## LDAP configuration
>
> ## General Configuration  sonar.security.realm=LDAP
>
> ## sonar.security.savePassword=false
>
> ## sonar.forceAuthentication=true  ldap.url=ldap://ad.yyy.xxx.com:389  ldap.bindDN=CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=yyy,DC=xxx,DC=com
>
> ldap.bindPassword=xxxx@ddddd
>
> ## User Configuration
>
> ## ldap.user.baseDn=CN=Users,DC=yyy,DC=xxx,DC=com  ldap.user.baseDn=DC=xxx,DC=com
>
> ## ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))  ldap.user.request=(sAMAccountName={0})
>
> ## ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
>
> ## ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn  ldap.user.realNameAttribute=displayName  ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
>
> sonar.log.level=DEBUG

While connecting AD user I am getting the following error.

> 2017.05.19 21:14:43 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, comment: In order to
>   perform this operation a successful bind m ust be completed on the
>   connection., data 0, v2580]  javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP:
>   error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090752, comment: In order to
>   perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the con
>   nection., data 0, v2580] 
>          at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3175) ~[na:1.8.0_91] 
>          at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>
> 2017.05.19 21:14:43 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] User ajeesh not found in  
>   2017.05.19 21:14:43 ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::OrgSonarPluginsLdap::LdapException: Unable
>   to retrieve details for user ajeesh in

Comment: Sorry for the woring format.                              
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://ad.yyy.xxx.com:389
ldap.bindDN=CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=yyy,DC=xxx,DC=com
ldap.bindPassword=xxxxxxxxx1
ldap.user.baseDn=DC=xxx,DC=com
ldap.user.request=(sAMAccountName={0})
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=displayName
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

sonar.log.level=DEBUG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819620/errot-while-integrating-sonarqube-with-ldap) SO question.